# How to Find a Period-Three Cycle

Tags: dynamical-systems, chaos-theory

I have learnt that a period-two cycle, say of the logistic map $$x_{k+1}=rx_k-rx_k^2, \ \ x_k\in (0,1), \ \ r\in (0,4),$$
can be found by finding $x_k=x_{k+2}$ where $x_k\neq x_{k+1}$. For this logistic map, the period-two cycle is $$x_0=\frac{1+r+\sqrt{(r-3)(r+1)}}{2r} \\ x_1=\frac{1+r-\sqrt{(r-3)(r+1)}}{2r},$$ where $r\geq 3$. I am curious how the three cycle is found. Do we simply search for $x_k=x_{k+3}$, where $x_k\neq x_{k+1}$ and $x_k\neq x_{k+2}$? I could not find an example in my lecture notes, and I am wondering how a period-three cycle could be obtained in general (assuming this can be done be hand).

Comment: That's basically it, yes. One minor point: The conditions $x_k=x_{k+3}\neq x_{k+1}$ imply $x_k\neq x_{k+2}$, so the latter condition is actually redundant. So all you need to do is find period-3 points which aren't fixed points. Numerically that's not so bad for a given value of $r$, since $x_{k+3}$ is a degree-8 polynomial in $x_k$. Doing so analytically, however, is certainly harder.

Comment: @Semiclassical Awesome. For example, how difficult is it to find the period-three cycle for the aforementioned logistic map by hand? If you wish to submit this as an answer, I would most certainly upvote.

Comment: It's as difficult as finding the real roots of a degree-8 polynomial. Which is to say: Easy enough if you only care about numerical values, but typically intractable if you want exact values. The challenge only grows worse if you want higher cycles: the period-$n$ points will be the roots $x\in (0,1)$ of a degree-$2^n$ polynomial. So getting analytical results for the logistic map is probably a nonstarter.

Comment: One exception to that rule: There is a minimum value $r_0$ for the logistic map $x\mapsto f(x)$ to have 3-cycles. For $r>r_0$, the real roots of $f(f(f(x)))=x$ will consist of two fixed points ($x=0$ and $x=1-1/r$) and six points of least period 3 (i.e. two 3-cycles). For $r<r_0$, you only have the two fixed points as real roots. In the case $r=r_0$, the six nontrivial roots are all double roots. That's a strong enough condition that $r_0$ can be found explicitly to be $1+2\sqrt{2}$.